# How to "capture" drop multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, drop

I know one can drop multiple columns with

```
df.drop(columns=['col1', 'col2'],inplace=True)
```

I want to drop only if a column exists without throwing an error if it does not.
For example, if only col2 exists, it should only drop col2. I know this can be done via a loop, or I can write my function, but I'm looking for a more native solution.

Comment: Don't use `inplace=True`, it will be deprecated => https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529

Comment: @Corralien What is the alternative to inplace=true from a memory management perspective?

Comment: If memory management is important for you, switch to pyarrow or downcast numeric types to avoid float64 / int64. Use category dtype to manage finite number of categories. These actions will reduce the memory footprint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore errors:

```
df.drop(columns=['col1', 'col2'], inplace=True, errors='ignore')
```